# SoftLayer API Hardware : createObject : postInstallScriptUri : ObjectStorage

Tags: ibm-cloud-infrastructure

During Provision of BM Server, we can use postInstallScriptUri for installing/running user defiend scripts. Refer the payload as mentioned below.

Object Storage URL :

> https://dal05.objectstorage.softlayer.net/auth/v1.0/test/agility.sh

The above objectStorage URL is not accessible. It's public URL. Please let me know how to access the data from ObjectStorage. I don't want use the credentials and authorization key using REST API. Directly i want to access the files. (similar to amazon s3 storage).

```
{"parameters": [{"datacenter": {"name": "dal01" },
        "hostname": "vijscript",
        "domain": "test.com",
        "hourlyBillingFlag":"",
        "fixedConfigurationPreset": {
            "keyName": "S1270_8GB_2X1TBSATA_NORAID"
        },
        "operatingSystemReferenceCode": "WIN_2012-STD_64",
         "postInstallScriptUri" : `"https://dal05.objectstorage.softlayer.net/auth/v1.0/test/agility.sh"     
    }]
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Probably enabling the CDN can be the best option for you, it can be done through [Control Portal](https://control.softlayer.com):

Follow these steps:

> 1. Click Storage
> 2. Select Object Storage (e.g. SLOS3011111-10).
> 3. Select Cluster (e.g. Paris 1)
> 4. Select Container (e.g. ContainerTest)
> 5. Click on "Enable CDN" option
> 6. Select the file's row
> 7. On the right side the "HTTP URL" will be displayed